# How to pro-grammatically generate Struct Type as StringType for all the fields in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have *n number of fields(like 200-300), all the fields Struct Type i want as string-type only. Any simple way are there, like below mentioned

`val schema = StructType(schemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName ⇒ StructField(fieldName, StringType, true)))`

Below code  i tried,

```java
StructType schema= new StructType()
        .add("field1", StringType)
        .add("field2", StringType)
        .add("field3", StringType);

ExpressionEncoder express=RowCoder.apply(schema)
```

Comment: whatever you mentioned is a good solution. that should be the simple and right answer.

Comment: How schemaString looks like?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis schemaString in row format

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern Matching

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = Seq(
  (1L, BigDecimal(12.34), "a", BigDecimal(10.001)),
  (2L, BigDecimal(56.78), "b", BigDecimal(20.002))
).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

val newSchema = df.schema.fields.map{
  case StructField(name, _: DecimalType, nullable, _)
    => StructField(name, DoubleType, nullable)
  case field => field
}
```

Comment: Whatever I mentioned in Scala it's very simple , and i need to convert that code into java